# Can I use the content of div:before as an anchor to toggle visibility of the rest of the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following css (idea from [blog post](http://drz.ac/2013/01/17/latex-theorem-like-environments-for-the-web/) of Zachary Harmany):

```
.proof{
    display: block;
    content: "Proof:";
}
.proof:before {
    content: inherit;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Then html

```
<div class="proof"> This is trivial. </div>
```

produces something like:

> *Proof:*
>
> This is trivial.

I would like to use the "Proof:" keyword to toggle the visibility of the proof (here the sentence "This is trivial.") *onclick*.

Is it possible to use the content of .proof:before as an anchor to toggle the visibility of the rest of the content of .proof?

Comment: As far as I’m aware you can not attach event handlers specifically to pseudo elements. But in case you make only the pseudo element visible and hide the rest of the divs content, a click event for the div itself should fire when the pseudo element is clicked as well.

Comment: @CBroe :focus/active and pointer-events can help , run codesnippet in my answer and click on pseudo content :)

Comment: @GCyrillus: I was referring to JS event handlers, which he seemed to be specifically asking about.

Comment: @CBroe i understood that, pseudo are not in the DOM tree, but clicking on it triggers the onclick event on its element . so  divElement.onclick will work clicking on the pseudo element.  Same process that my CSS example shows ;) (=>javascript seems not avalaible in the snippets http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaOpXQ )

Comment: @GCyrillus well, that is exactly what I said …

Comment: @CBroe, oups, time to take a break i guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is yes :

maybe `height` and `pointer-events` can help to show you that it is possible:

```css
.proof{
  height:1.2em;
  overflow:hidden;
  pointer-events:auto;

}
.proof:before {
  content: "Proof: onclick toggles show/hide real content";
  display:block;
  font-style: italic;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.proof:active , .proof:focus {
  height:auto;
  pointer-events:none;
  outline:none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="proof" tabindex="0"> This is trivial. you see me or not onclick :) </div>
```

So you need to catch the onclick from the element itself. 
If you hover or click the pseudo-elements, you do meanwhile click or hover the element itself.

Comment: No, this is exactly what I wanted to achieve - thank you! Two observations: Without tabindex=0, the div is only shown while clicking "Proof". Is it possible to integrate this necessary specification into the css? Also, when shown, the proof is shown as "selected": in both Firefox and Chrome a frame around the div is displayed. Is there any way to get rid of this?

Comment: @FelixHoffmann for the tabindex attribute  you need it in HTML  in order to give focus, only links and form elements have this defaut behavior. For the 'selected' visual, you can remove it with : outline:none;

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use dom attributes as psuedo children

```
<div class="proof" state="proof"> This is trivial. </div>

.proof:before{content: attr(state) ": ";}
```

If you now target the dom elements attribute, you might be a step closer to figuring things out